# OnChanges doesnt fire if @Input is an object & one of its property updates

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

**What I'm trying to do ?**

I have a parent component(say `parent`) which contains 2 children components(say `child-1` and `child-2`). When one of the DOM element value within child 1 changes, I'm assigning the new value to one of the properties of an object and emitting the object to parent. Parent then assigns the incoming object to its own local object, which I'm passing as an input(`[setupValues]`) to child 2 component. Within Child 2, when there is any change to that `@Input` object, I want to assign one of its properties to a local variable(which is not happening because the child 2 `Onchanges` doesn't get fired even when one of the properties within `@Input` object has changed).

**My Source Code**(most removed due to brevity)

Consider I have an interface `ISetups.ts`

```
export interface ISetups {
  DOB: string;
  DOD: string;
  DOE: string;
}
```

Markup of `parent.html` goes as follows

```
<child-1 [input]="someVariable" (setupsChanged)="onSetupsChange($event)">
</child-1>

{{ allSetups.DOB }} <!-- the change is shown correctly here -->

<child-2 [setupValues]="allSetups"></child-2>
```

In `parent.ts`

```
export class ParentComponent {

  someVariable: string;
  allSetups: ISetups;

  onSetupsChange(allSetups: ISetups) {
    // emitted object from child 1 is assigned to local object
    this.allSetups = allSetups;
  }
}
```

In `child-1.html`

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ownDOB" (blur)="emitChange()" >
```

In `child-1.ts`

```
export class Child1Component {

  @Input() input: string;
  @Output() setupsChanged: EventEmitter<ISetups> = new EventEmitter<ISetups>();
  allSetups: ISetups;
  ownDOB: string;

  emitChange() {
    this.allSetups.DOB = this.ownDOB;
    this.setupsChanged.emit(this.allSetups); //emitting object to parent
  }
}
```

In `child-2.html`

```
<p>{{ localDOB }}</p>
```

In `child-2.ts`

```
export class Child2Component implements OnChanges {

  localDOB: string;
  @Input() setupValues: ISetups;

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.log("this does not fire if setupValues.DOB changes");
    this.localDOB = this.setupValues.DOB;
  }

}
```

**What worked ?**

Passing the property directly as another input worked

```
<child-2 [DOB]="allSetups.DOB" [setupValues]="allSetups"></child-2>
```

The above works but obviously its not a nice way & I don't want to do this.

The above proves that when I send the variable on its own, it fires the `OnChanges` but doesn't fire when just one of the properties within an object is changed.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happened because your reference to object is not changed, so if in your parent.ts change your code to this, it should work. By this way (using `spread operator`) you are creating a new instance of object

```
onSetupsChange(allSetups: ISetups) {
    // emitted object from child 1 is assigned to local object
    this.allSetups = {...allSetups};
  }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Not familiar with that syntax. Can you perhaps provide a link or more explanation as to what the `...` does ? Just create a new instance of the object ? Also considering it creates a new instance, does it not create memory issues ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa this is called `spread operator` you can more about it which is related to your case in http://lucybain.com/blog/2018/js-es6-spread-operator/

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot. Was just a little worried about the memory implications. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa won't be an issue, if it works kindly mark it as answer, in case other users having same issue